# Replace a word after a significant line and white spaces (inline) using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following text:

```
  A
  Hello
  world
  B
  Hello
  world
  C
  Hello
  world
```

I know that I can replace `Hello` by `Hi` using `sed`:

```
sed 's/Hello/Hi/g' -i test
```

but this replace each `Hello` with `Hi`:

```
  A
  Hi
  world
  B
  Hi
  world
  C
  Hi
  world
```

what I really want is to replace only the `Hello` after `B`:

```
  A
  Hello
  world
  B
  Hi
  world
  C
  Hello
  world
```

so I have tried this:

```
sed 's/"B\nHello"/"B\nHi"/g' -i test
```

but nothing happened, How can I do this?

Note: There are some white-spaces on the beginning of each line of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*B$/{n;s/Hello/Hi/g;}'
```

That assumes there are no consecutive `B`s (one `B` line followed by another `B` line).

Otherwise, you could do:

```
awk 'last ~ /^[[:blank:]]*B$/ {gsub("Hello", "Hi")}; {print; last=$0}'
```

The `sed` equivalent would be:

```
sed 'x;/^[[:blank:]]*B$/{
       g;s/Hello/Hi/;b
     }
     g'
```

To replace the second word after `B`, or to replace `world` with `universe` only if two lines above contained `B`:

```
awk 'l2 ~ /B/ {gsub("world","universe")}; {print; l2=l1; l1=$0}'
```

To generalise it to `n` lines above:

```
awk -v n=12 'l[NR%n] ~ /B/ {gsub("foo", "bar")}; {print; l[NR%n]=$0}'
```

Comment: it didn't work, I guess because the file have `white-spaces` on the beginning of each line

Comment: @Networker, see edit. You could also use `/B/` if you only need to check that the line contains `B` or `/B$/` to check that it ends in `B`.

Comment: Thanks this worked but How can I do the changes inline (to the file) using `awk`

Comment: @Networker, with GNU `awk` 4.1.0 and above, use `awk -i inplace '...'`.

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas, what if I want to replace the second word after B: `World` by `guys` for example

Comment: @Networker, see edit

Comment: But how can I achieve this using `sed`

Comment: @Networker, Not easily. Use `awk` or `perl` when it gets tricky in `sed`. (`perl` also has in-place editing with `-i`, that's where GNU `sed` copied it from).

Answer (score 1):

You can add command to find white before and after Bs

Assuming u1 is

```
A
Hello
world
 B
Hello
world
C
Hello
world
  B   (<-tailing whites)
Hello
world
```

use the command

```
sed '/^[ ]*B[ ]*$/{n;s/Hello/Hi/;}' u1
A
Hello
world
 B
Hi
world
C
Hello
world
  B
Hi
world
```

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` can handle the case when you have two consecutive `B`:

```
$ sed ':a
/B$/{$!N;/\n[[:blank:]]*Hello$/!ba;s/Hello/Hi/}
' file
```

Comment: Note that `/[[:blank:]]*B$/` is the same as `/B$/`. That syntax implies GNU `sed`.